# evalute string with math and numbers as variables

Tags: php

I have a math expression where I want to insert some different numeric variables to check if the expression is true or false..

But how to do it? I need the fastest way to do it because the expression is iterated many times

The expression must be a string

```
$exp = '$amount * $qty / 100 == $total';

$amount = 300;
$qty = 200;
$total = 500;

echo eval("$exp");
```

Comment: So the calculation is always the same, the difference is the values and the total you're comparing to? I don't see why you need eval for that at all.

Comment: Is the exp always same ?

Comment: yes its always the same

Comment: Speed? `$expr = function($a, $q, $t){return $a * $q / 100 == $t}` Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `return` keyword inside the evaluated string. Also, you have to use a final `;` to be a valid expression.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

> **Return Values**
>   eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned.

```
$exp = 'return $amount * $qty / 100 == $total;';
$amount = 300;
$qty = 200;
$total = 500;
var_dump(eval("$exp")); // false
```

Comment: It works :) But what if I want to print the whole expression also after the variables are inserted? https://www.tehplayground.com/eMHcBy9i79Wa22mB

Comment: @clarkk You could use `preg_replace_callback()` : https://eval.in/979538

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is always the same, then you don't need to use a string like that. A function is faster to be implemented and run:

```
<?php
function calc($amount, $quantity)
{
    return $amount * $quantity / 100;
}

echo sprintf('%.2f', calc(300, 200));
```

Now I'll assume you want to implement a calculator using a string as input.

There are several ways to do it, but `eval` is not a good answer.

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.

The easiest way is using a library, for instance, this:
https://github.com/chriskonnertz/string-calc

If you're using Linux, BSD or MacOSX - and you can run shell commands -, you might run `bc` shell command:

```
<?php
$expr = '300 * 200 / 100';
$result = (float)exec('echo ' . escapeshellarg($expr) . ' | bc');
echo sprintf('%.2f', $result);
```

Probably most shared hosting don't allow that (and they neither allow `eval`).

You could also implement a parser, just like StringCalc. You would need to isolate the tokens (usually using regex) and create a binary tree, taking into account the operators priorities.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rl3fc7dJ6Xs